# Script not working as intended even though they should be fundamentally the same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been working on a strategy defense game where you send your troops to the enemy base and deplete their base HP to 0. So here's the problem, two scripts I have should be working the same, two scripts for enemy melee logic and player melee logic, but when I run the game, the player troops still don't move even when the ally in front of them is destroyed, but the enemy logic still works fine. Am I missing something here? Here are the scripts:

PLayer melee logic:

```
public class MeleeTroopLogic : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private float AttackSpeed;
    [SerializeField] public float Damage;
    [SerializeField] private float ViewRange;
    [SerializeField] private float BoundaryRange;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask EnemyLayer;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask FriendlyLayer;
    [SerializeField] private float ColliderDistance;
    [SerializeField] private float FriendlyColliderDistance;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D AttackRange;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D SpaceDistance;
    private float AttackCooldown = Mathf.Infinity;

    Health TroopHealth;
    PlayerTroopsMovement Move;

    private Animator anim;


    private void Awake()
    {
        Move = GetComponentInParent<PlayerTroopsMovement>();
        
        
    }
    void Update()
    {
        AttackCooldown += Time.deltaTime;
        if(Enemydetected())
        {
            Move.MovementSpeed = 0;

            if(AttackCooldown >= AttackSpeed)
            {
                AttackCooldown = 0;
                Attack();
            }
        }

        if(Move != null)
        {
            Move.enabled = !(Enemydetected() || AllyDetected()); 
            
        }

        
    }

    private bool Enemydetected()
    {
        
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(AttackRange.bounds.center + transform.right * ViewRange * ColliderDistance, new Vector3(AttackRange.bounds.size.x * ViewRange, AttackRange.bounds.size.y, AttackRange.bounds.size.z),0,Vector2.right, 0, EnemyLayer);
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            TroopHealth = hit.transform.GetComponentInChildren<Health>();
        }
        return hit.collider != null;
    }

    private bool AllyDetected()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(SpaceDistance.bounds.center + transform.right * BoundaryRange * FriendlyColliderDistance, new Vector3(SpaceDistance.bounds.size.x * BoundaryRange, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.y, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.z), 0, Vector2.right, 0, FriendlyLayer);
        return hit.collider != null;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        EnemyGizmo();
        AllyGizmo();
    }

    private void EnemyGizmo()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(AttackRange.bounds.center + transform.right * ViewRange * ColliderDistance, new Vector3(AttackRange.bounds.size.x * ViewRange, AttackRange.bounds.size.y, AttackRange.bounds.size.z));
    }

    private void AllyGizmo()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(SpaceDistance.bounds.center + transform.right * BoundaryRange * FriendlyColliderDistance, new Vector3(SpaceDistance.bounds.size.x * ViewRange, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.y, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.z));
    }

    
    private void Attack()
    {
        if(TroopHealth != null)
        {
            TroopHealth.TakeDamage(Damage);
        }
    }

}
```

And for the enemy Logic

```
public class EnemyMeleeTroopLogic : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private float AttackSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float Damage;
    [SerializeField] private float ViewRange;
    [SerializeField] private float BoundaryRange;
    [SerializeField] private float ColliderDistance;
    [SerializeField] private float FriendlyColliderDistance;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask FriendlyLayer;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask EnemyLayer;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D AttackRange;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D SpaceDistance;
    private float AttackCooldown = Mathf.Infinity;

    Health TroopHealth;
    EnemyTroopsMovement Move;

    private Animator anim;


    private void Awake()
    {
        Move = GetComponentInParent<EnemyTroopsMovement>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        AttackCooldown += Time.deltaTime;
        if (Enemydetected())
        {
            
            if (AttackCooldown >= AttackSpeed)
            {
                AttackCooldown = 0;
                Attack();
            }
        }

        if (Move != null)
        {
            Move.enabled = !(Enemydetected() || AllyDetected());
        }

    }

    private bool Enemydetected()
    {

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(AttackRange.bounds.center + transform.right * ViewRange * ColliderDistance, new Vector3(AttackRange.bounds.size.x * ViewRange, AttackRange.bounds.size.y, AttackRange.bounds.size.z), 0, Vector2.left, 0, FriendlyLayer);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            TroopHealth = hit.transform.GetComponentInChildren<Health>();
        }
        return hit.collider != null;
    }

    private bool AllyDetected()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(SpaceDistance.bounds.center + transform.right * BoundaryRange * FriendlyColliderDistance, new Vector3(SpaceDistance.bounds.size.x * BoundaryRange, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.y, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.z), 0, Vector2.right, 0, EnemyLayer);
        return hit.collider != null;
    }


    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        EnemyGizmo();
        AllyGizmo();
    }

    private void EnemyGizmo()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(AttackRange.bounds.center + transform.right * ViewRange * ColliderDistance, new Vector3(AttackRange.bounds.size.x * ViewRange, AttackRange.bounds.size.y, AttackRange.bounds.size.z));
    }

    private void AllyGizmo()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(SpaceDistance.bounds.center + transform.right * BoundaryRange * FriendlyColliderDistance, new Vector3(SpaceDistance.bounds.size.x * ViewRange, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.y, SpaceDistance.bounds.size.z));
    }

    private void Attack()
    {
        if (TroopHealth != null)
        {
            TroopHealth.TakeDamage(Damage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself duplicating a lot of code like this take a step back and figure out what is really different and figure out how to handle that rather than the copy/paste. At a glance the only difference I see is `PlayerTroopsMovement` versus `EnemyTroopsMovement`. I would look at the difference between those two since that is likely where the issue is, and perhaps figure out how to combine them as well so the only difference is which component you assign to the object. If the two classes are different then perhaps an interface would work but hard to say without seeing them.

Comment: Thank you, I am of the same opinion as well, just that it was driving me insane because I know that I have overlooked something but just can't seem to figure out what it is. I'll take your word and look into this from the bottom of the situation

Comment: There is a bit more difference in those two files. Use an editor or merge program that will let you compare them to see what is different.  `Move.MovementSpeed = 0;` looks supect since it is only in the script that does not work and I don't see anywhere in that script where it would be changed from 0 to something else. Again, involves code we cannot see.

Comment: Enemydetected is this function worked ??

Comment: Yes, I also saw that, somehow the me few days ago thought that it was a good idea to somehow set the movement to 0 PERMANENTLY. Thank you Retired Ninja. Also yes TimChang the enemydetected function works. Thank you too TimChang.

Comment: @RGVC Things that keep programmers awake at night... wondering what they did yesterday that they'll find tomorrow and have no idea why they did it. :)